# Using NULLIF or Coalesce in CTE - Data type conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following CTE inside a view and I would like to add some NULLIF (or equivalent) function so that If `WTHD_BOX16` is `NULL` then replace with an empty string (blank), otherwise display the value.

```
WITH VWDETAIL  AS 
( SELECT VENDOR_ID , 'PA/13679089' AS WTHD_BOX17 , WTHD_BASIS_AMT AS WTHD_BOX18 , YEAR(PYMNT_DT) AS YEAR , 
  CASE WHEN PYMNT_DT <= '01/31/2014' THEN '1099' ELSE 'NGC' END AS WTHD_CNTL_ID 
  FROM PS_WTHD_TRXN_TBL A 
  WHERE WTHD_CLASS IN ('01','02','07') 
   AND BUSINESS_UNIT IN ('10000','50000') 
   AND PYMNT_DT <= CASE BUSINESS_UNIT WHEN '10000' THEN '01/31/2014' ELSE '12/31/2018'  END)

  , BOX16DATA AS

 ( SELECT --A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.VOUCHER_ID, 
A.PYMNT_TYPE, SUM(A.PAID_AMT) AS BOX16PAIDAMT, SUM(A.PYMNT_GROSS_AMT) AS WTHD_BOX16, B.VENDOR_ID, YEAR(A.SCHEDULED_PAY_DT) AS 'Year'
FROM PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF A
INNER JOIN PS_VOUCHER B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
WHERE PYMNT_TYPE = 'W'
AND REMIT_VENDOR = '47860A'
GROUP BY B.VENDOR_ID,  A.PYMNT_TYPE, YEAR(A.SCHEDULED_PAY_DT)
) 

SELECT A.VENDOR_ID, B.WTHD_BOX16,  WTHD_BOX17 , SUM(WTHD_BOX18) AS WTHD_BOX18 , YEAR , WTHD_CNTL_ID  
FROM VWDETAIL A
LEFT OUTER JOIN BOX16DATA B ON B.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID AND B.Year = YEAR
GROUP BY A.VENDOR_ID , WTHD_BOX17 , YEAR , WTHD_CNTL_ID, B.WTHD_BOX16
ORDER BY A.YEAR
GO
```

I added the `NULLIF` to the final `Select` statement, however I am getting back the error 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'.

```
SELECT A.VENDOR_ID, NULLIF(B.WTHD_BOX16, ''),  WTHD_BOX17 , SUM(WTHD_BOX18) AS WTHD_BOX18 , YEAR , WTHD_CNTL_ID  
FROM VWDETAIL A
LEFT OUTER JOIN BOX16DATA B ON B.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID AND B.Year = YEAR
GROUP BY A.VENDOR_ID , WTHD_BOX17 , YEAR , WTHD_CNTL_ID, B.WTHD_BOX16
ORDER BY A.YEAR
GO
```

How can I fix this so that I will have the numeric values if there isn't a NULL and an empty string for a NULL row? Using MS SQL Server.

Comment: you probably want 0 if the column is numeric.  use `NULLIF(B.WTHD_BOX16, 0)` or `COALESCE(B.WTHD_BOX16,0)` instead

Comment: I would rather have a blank (empty string) if it is returned as NULL

Comment: You can't have an empty string -- **it isn't a string!**

Comment: `ISNULL(CAST(B.WTHD_BOX16 AS VARCHAR(50)), '') AS WTHD_BOX16` seems to work in the final Select query.

Comment: Ok that changes what types your select is returning... does that work calling application?

Comment: The entire CTE queries above are a SQL View. There is an application level program that calls this view. Do you foresee an issue with this outside SSMS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can cast the columns to varchar e.g. cast(col as varchar(50)). blank cannot be converted to numeric.

Comment: e.g. isnull(cast(SUM(A.PYMNT_GROSS_AMT) as varchar(50)),'') AS WTHD_BOX16

Comment: That does not work when I run the entire query. I am still getting NULL values in WTHD_BOX16 column...

Comment: use the cast in the last select statement e.g. SELECT A.VENDOR_ID, isnull(cast(B.WTHD_BOX16 as varchar(50),''),  WTHD_BOX17 , SUM(WTHD_BOX18) AS WTHD_BOX18 , YEAR , WTHD_CNTL_ID

Comment: `ISNULL(CAST(B.WTHD_BOX16 AS VARCHAR(50)), '') AS WTHD_BOX16` seems to work!